# Does anyone have printer drivers for a HP Color LaserJet 1600 on Mac OSX 10.7?

Tags: macos, drivers, hp-laserjet

Does anyone have printer drivers for a HP Color LaserJet 1600 on Mac OSX 10.7?  Or really does anyone have a good solution for installing drivers?

We set up the foo2hp but it doesn't seem to support everything for the 1600.
http://foo2hp.rkkda.com/

If someone has a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on the Apple Support site.  Remember that the solution for foo2hp is much older, while its a decent solution this one is better.  Seems like they're now offering HP drivers for their new flavors of OSX.

(HP Color LaserJet 1600 is similar to the HP Color LaserJet 2600)

Here's a support article updated as of July 5th, 2012:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3669#HP

Here's the file download:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL907

Answer (score 0):

> **We set up the foo2hp**

That is the correct driver (at least in Linux land) according to [openprinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-Color_LaserJet_1600).

> **but it doesn't seem to support everything for the 1600**

The PPD file usually determines what features are supported.

---

http://www.openprinting.org/driver/foo2hp/ says

> PPD files (and the Foomatic XML files to generate them) come with the driver

See http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz

---

This sort of issue is why I only buy printers that support PCL5 and Postscript (or emulations of these) - I still have enough problems with printers.